# Java equivalent of C++ sf_readf_double()

Tags: java, c++, android, audio, libsndfile

I'm manipulating .wav audio files in Android.
So far things are going well (I can record a .wav file from the mic, add echoes etc.), but I'd like to mimic the behaviour of `sf_readf_double()` and `sf_writef_double` as per [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#readf) in C++ to implement more complex filters.
I have a com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader and WaveFileWriter objects and I'm getting at the audio data using

```
stream = wfr.getAudioInputStream(new File(inputAudioFileName));
```

which returns an [AudioInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html).
Is it just a case of reading 8 bytes from the stream at a time into a double or is there more to it than that? I'm a little confused as other filters I'm using seem to manipulate `short`s rather than `double`s.

Comment: Please use newlines to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[What should I use in Android when porting C++ code written with libsndfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047251/what-should-i-use-in-android-when-porting-c-code-written-with-libsndfile)

Check this:

[android-ndk](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/78ee99c4efb4271b?pli=1)

Comment: Thanks Leniel, but that's my own question. I've since abandoned the JNI route, so that's not much help.

Comment: Oh... sorry, should have looked the asker! :)

Comment: Thanks for the ndk link, that looks pretty useful, although I have no experience with the ndk/jni. I'll have a look and see if I can get it working though.